# Referencing Environment with Global Python Variables

Tags: python, reference, global-variables

In the following program, there is a global variable, a, that I want to check the number of references to at each of the points 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```py
import sys

a = 'my-string'
print(sys.getrefcount(a))

b = [a]
print(sys.getrefcount(a))

del b
print(sys.getrefcount(a))

c = { 'key': a }
print(sys.getrefcount(a))
```

When I executed the program, I saw that the number of references were 4, 5, 4, 5, respectively. I do not understand why this is so.

My first thought was that all the global variables are allocated from the static segment of the stack, so, for each of `a`, `b = [a]`, and `c = { 'key': a }`, there is a reference, making up 3 references. And for each `print(sys.getrefcount(a))`, there is a reference, making up 4 references in total.

If that is the case, where does the 5th reference come from in the statements after `b = [a]` and `c = { 'key': a }`, especially after `b` is deleted?

Comment: References aren't to variables, they're to values.

Comment: So, the references are to 'my-string', the value of a in the list b, and the value of a that is mapped to key? Do I get this right?

Comment: Yes. In addition, there's a reference in the argument list of `sys.getrefcount()`.

Comment: In that case, where does the 5th reference come from? Also, does deleting b delete the reference to the value of a?

Comment: I'm not sure where all the references are, they may be internal.

Comment: It's easy to see why it goes up when you add the string to a list or dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much, there still remains a confusion but I guess it might be internal as you suggest.

Comment: Interestingly, if the value is a list, it alternates 2 3 2 3. I suspect there's a string cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to what the refreneces are is:

- Unknown internal, not the string cache since this also happens for other immutable literals like floats or ints (outside the -5 to 255 range). Maybe an artifact of the parsing?
- The constant table of the code object for the module
- The entry in the locals of the frame for the code object (in this case, the `globals()` dictionary)
- The refrences that was created when passing the string object to `getrefcount`
- And the one that changes: The reference in the collections.

You can observe a few interesting things about the way CPython works:

- Since same literals are the exact same object through the entire code, if you refer to `"my-string"` directly instead of `a` throughout the entire code the numbers wont change
- If you use literals like floats, large/negative ints, non-empty tuples and similar stuff, the behavior will be the exact same.
- If you use small ints, empty tuples, boolean literals or similar magic objects you will see different things depending on your version of CPython: Either a number that is quite a bit higher than for everything else, or you will see a *very* large number meaning that the highest bit has been flipped to indicate an imoortal object.

  - This also includes interned strings you might not expect, like `__init__`.
- If you use mutable objects like a list literal `[]`, or `object()`, `set()`, you will instead see a pattern `2,3,2,3`, indicating that the first two entires in the list above are no longer present.